# Magento2 - Unable to Manage Options (Values of Your Attribute) in Product Attribute

Tags: custom-attributes, magento2.3.1, magento2.3.4

I am baffled. I cannot add to, or reorder existing product attributes. (**Note:** `This is a site I inherited, so I didn't build it`.).

I have `max_input_vars` set at `20000`, up from `10000`. Nothing I try works. It simply doesn't save in the database, and I get no error messages.

Using `Magento EE 2.3.4`, but the issue is also on `2.3.1` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, more information would be needed to get to the bottom of this problem. I should ask this: I am not clear on whether or not this issue happens on the product edit page or an attribute's edit page?

*I suggest:*

- Set a breakpoint at the first line of `pub/index.php` (or `index.php` if that is the entry point). Evaluate the incoming `$_POST` vars.
- Set a breakpoint in the `beforeSave` method in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php`. What data is attached to `$this->_data`?
- Review the logs in `var/log`.
- Disable some modules in `app/etc/config.php`.

This should get you closer to your solution.

Comment: I wasn't in developer mode, so I did that. I tried saving, and got something in debug.log:

cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://REDACTED.docksal/REDACTED/catalog/product_attribute/save/attribute_id/398/active_tab/main/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["EAV","EAV_ATTRIBUTE"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"}} []
cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://REDACTED.docksal/REDACTED/catalog/product_attribute/save/attribute_id/398/active_tab/main/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["EAV_ATTRIBUTE"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"}} []

Comment: Continued ...

cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://REDACTED.docksal/REDACTED/catalog/product_attribute/save/attribute_id/398/active_tab/main/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["EAV_ATTRIBUTE_398","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2020-03-28 02:27:25] report.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://REDACTED.docksal/REDACTED/admin/cache/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"LOCKED_RECORD_INFO_BLOCK_475f152da3bdbc695fdfc6419908aa7c64cb0c0d"}} []

I'm just not sure what to do with this information.

Comment: When I set a breakpoint on index.php in the site I'm working on, I'm not seeing the ajax form's POST variables come through. But, when I do that on a vanilla Magento install, I do see POST variables.

Setting a breakpoint at in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php` does nothing. It never catches with xdebug.

I don't see variables in the ajax headers in the network tab in Chrome either.

Could this be a migration issue from M1 to M2? Some other module? I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: One hint there is to set a breakpoint at the `class` line. That will trip when the class is autoloaded. Second, if you are not seeing any POST variables, this almost guaranteed points to a webserver configuration issue (Apache/Nginx or PHP). You could do a simple test to make sure that this works in general—create a file that posts a variable to itself.

Comment: I would also suggest to enable query logging to see what all queries are getting fired. It might be that some code is overwritten and it is preventing it from being added. But, it would be a good starting point to begin with what @JosephatSwiftOtter mentioned, put the breakpoints.

Comment: I would also suggest to check apache/nginx/php error log. Also see if you have limit on post data size and also see the request headers and post data from the browser what all is being posted